# How do you make a complete backup?

Tags: iphone, backup

On Android, you can use recovery to make a complete NANDROID backup, which when restored, is exactly the way you left the system. What would be the iDevice equivalent of this and how would one go about making one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPods and iPhones are backed up using iTunes to a Mac or PC.

"On this iPhone" has options to backup either to iCloud or the device running iTunes.

Comment: When I restore the backup, everything will be restored to that point?

Comment: Yes - otherwise if you have something bad introduced onto the phone, it would still be there if you didn't go back to the time of the backup.